# Kubernetes Spring Cloud Multiple Config Maps being used

Tags: kubernetes, spring-cloud

As per the documentation at - https://github.com/spring-cloud-incubator/spring-cloud-kubernetes/#configmap-propertysource, it is possible to make ConfigMaps available during application bootstrapping through adding `spring.cloud.kubernetes.config.name` to the `bootstrap.yaml/properties`.

Is it possible to consume multiple ConfigMaps in this manner?

I believe it is possible to do this in the pod specification through the use of `env-from` - https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/. But it would be great to do this with the current setup that we have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in [ConfigMapPropertySource.java](https://github.com/fabric8io/spring-cloud-kubernetes/blob/master/spring-cloud-kubernetes-core/src/main/java/io/fabric8/spring/cloud/kubernetes/config/ConfigMapPropertySource.java), only one ConfigMap will be used by this property source.

However, using `envFrom`, all entries in a ConfigMap can be provided as environment variables to the container and [Spring Boot can also read environment variables](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html), so maybe this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the `spring.cloud.kubernetes.config.sources` config is also an option here. Here you can specify multiple configmaps.

See https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-kubernetes/1.0.0.M2/multi/multi__configmap_propertysource.html